# Why I can't add ON UPDATE option to several foreign keys pointing to the same field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables `users` and `bans`.

The second table has two columns `user_id_from` and `user_id_to` with foreign keys to column `id` of the first table. I set ON UPDATE option to both and it throw me an error. I work in VS with SQL Server and only get a message "Script execution error" without description.

The script is executing if I add an option for only one key but I can't understand why it's not working for both together like in the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE [users] 
(
    [id]               INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [bans] 
(
    [id]                 INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id_from]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [user_id_to]         INT           NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_1_bans_TO_users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([user_id_from]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([id]) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_2_bans_TO_users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([user_id_to]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([id]) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: What is your 1 question? Your title & 2 body questions disgree. And the last doesn't need the rest of the body. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. PS Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. [help] PS " it's not executing" is not helpful.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Googling 'sql server can't add two on delete' ... [MS SQL “ON DELETE CASCADE” multiple foreign keys pointing to the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5018099/3404097)

Comment: I apologize for the poor presentation of the question, this is the first time I do this, also I don't know much about the material. Now I figured it out, thanks for the link, I just assumed that this is a problem specifically in SQL, and not in SQL Server, so I didn't google it correctly. Thank you!

Comment: It won't be just SQL Server. However the details will probably vary for DBMSs. What could a rule be for chains of SQL FKs in general? It is not clear. What if the cascades disagree? Research it. I just started with that tag so you would get the most specific answers. I looked at exactly 1 hit after exactly 1 google. It answered your particular error message on your particular DBMS.  Also research site protocols & goals. Good luck. PS Duplicates should be closed as duplicates, not answers. See my comment on your answer & google the topic & others with 'site:meta.stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It is difficult to understand how everything works here, but it is amazing how many people influence one small process. Should I delete my answer and if so how, because I see the "undelete" instead of "delete" under it? Or should I delete the whole question?

Comment: Poorly received posts (which includes, no upvotes) count towards question bans whether deleted or not. This post is around forever. Why not edit per the comments & links to improve it, to merit upvotes & not downvotes? (As a duplicate it is bypassed for some readers but visible to others.). [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Do you mean that I should edit the question by adding an explanation of why this is happening and additional links if I find something I can refer to?

Comment: Please act on my 1st 2 comments. (Other than the duplicate search.) I don't understand how you can think you acted on them. If you have a question about a particular thing in my comments or links, ask for clarification in a comment. (Including, give minimal code & show "try to add ON DELETE or / and ON UPDATE to them, I can't do it for both".)

Comment: Okay, I edited the question, hopefully corrected the disagree of the questions and deleted extra code. But again - if the question is a duplicate, and I was just dumb for not finding the same question, should I just leave it as it is? Because the answer already exists